# Array to comma separated string?

Tags: php

My php code is

```
public function getAllAttributes()
    {
        $this->dao->select('b_title');
        $this->dao->from($this->getTable_buttonsAttr());
        $result = $this->dao->get();
        if( !$result ) {
            return array() ;
        }
        return $result->result();
    }

$details = Modelbuttons::newInstance()->getAllAttributes();
$string = implode(', ', $details);
var_dump ($string) ;  ?>
```

I get this an array that looks like this:

```
 array (size=6)
          0 => 
            array (size=1)
              'b_title' => string 'test 10' (length=12)
          1 => 
            array (size=1)
              'b_title' => string 'test 11' (length=12)
          2 => 
            array (size=1)
              'b_title' => string 'test 12' (length=13)
          3 => 
            array (size=1)
              'b_title' => string 'test 13' (length=8)
          4 => 
            array (size=1)
              'b_title' => string 'test 14' (length=14)
          5 => 
            array (size=1)
              'b_title' => string 'test 15' (length=32)
```

How can I transform this array to a string like this with PHP?

```
$out = '10, 11, 12, 13, 14,15';
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried in order to achieve this.

Comment: did u tried anything? any code plz share

Comment: I get   string 'Array, Array, Array, Array, Array, Array' (length=40)

Comment: Then, please share your code.

Comment: now u have lot of solutions try them

Comment: Ha Ha `:D` @devpro. Not Lot. Too Much.

Comment: @NanaPartykar: yes 9 Answer, 2 Deleted :)

Comment: @Ahmed: I think there are enough answers to your question. Please select the appropriate answer to your question by marking it as correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code.

```
$array = [['b_title' => 'test 10'],['b_title' => 'test 11']];
foreach($array as $a) {
    $values[] = explode(' ', $a['b_title'])[1];
}
echo implode(', ', $values);
```

Comment: tanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

**Basic Example:**

```
<?php
// your array
$array = array(
        array('b_title'=>'test 10'),
        array('b_title'=>'test 11'),
        array('b_title'=>'test 12'),
        array('b_title'=>'test 13')
    );

$newArr = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $newVal = explode(" ", $value['b_title']);
    $newArr[] = $newVal[1];
}
echo implode(',', $newArr); // 10,11,12,13
?>
```

**Explanation:**

First of all use [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) for your string value which help you to Split a string as required:

```
$newVal = explode(" ", $value['b_title']);
```

Than you can store index 1 in an array as:

```
$newArr[] = $newVal[1]; // array(10,11,12,13)
```

In last, you just need to use [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function which help you to get comma separated data.

```
echo implode(',', $newArr); // 10,11,12,13
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to do.

```
$details = Modelbuttons::newInstance()->getAllAttributes(); /*[['b_title' => 'test 10'],['b_title' => 'test 11']];*/
$token = "";
foreach($details as $row1){
 $token = $token.$row1['b_title'].", ";
}
echo rtrim(trim($token),",");
```

**Output**: test 10, test 11

***Explanation***

Through foreach, all array values are now comma separated.

As of now, output will be `test 10, test 11,`. So, remove extra comma which trail in the end through [rtrim()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_rtrim.asp).

Comment: This does not provide the required output `$out = '10, 11, 12, 13, 14,15';`

Comment: That will provide Mr @Blinkydamo, I checked it before posting answer. If you are talking about `$out` & `single quotes`, then may be.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Construct a new array of the stripped numbers
$flattenedArray = array_map(function($item) {
    list(, $number) = explode(' ', $item['b_title']);

    return $number;
}, $yourArray);

// Concatenate the numbers into a string joined by ,
$out = implode(', ', $flattenedArray);
```

This gives the result you want. It could do with a few conditions in there though to check arrays are in the correct format before manipulation etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to skin this cat -- Here's one:

```
<?php
$out = '';

foreach ($array as $arrayItem) {
    $out .= $arrayItem['b_title'] . ', ';
}

// Remove the extraneous ", " from the $out string.
$out = substr($out, 0, -2);
?>
```

Or if you were also wanting to remove the "test " portion of the 'b_title' key's value; then you could accomplish it like so:

```
<?php
$out = '';

foreach ($array as $arrayItem) {
    $out .= str_replace('test ', '', $arrayItem['b_title']) . ', ';

}

// Remove the extraneous ", " from the $out string.
$out = substr($out, 0, -2);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$test_array = array(
  0 => array('b_title' => 'test 10'),
  1 => array('b_title' => 'test 11'),
  2 => array('b_title' => 'test 12'),
  3 => array('b_title' => 'test 13'),
  4 => array('b_title' => 'test 14'),
  5 => array('b_title' => 'test 15'),
);
$result = "";
$result1 = array_walk($test_array, function ($value, $key) use(&$result) {
    $result .= ",".array_pop(explode(" ", reset($value))).",";
    $result = trim($result, ",");
});
```

Output: $out = '10, 11, 12, 13, 14,15';

**Explanation**

Iterate over array by using PHP's native array_walk() which will reduce forloops and then prepare array by using explode(),array_pop() and trim() which is likely required to prepare your required string.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also

```
$check  = array(array ('b_title' => array('test 10'))
    ,array('b_title' => array('test 11'))
    ,array('b_title' => array('test 12'))
    ,array('b_title' => array('test 13'))
    ,array('b_title' => array('test 14'))
    ,array('b_title' => array('test 15')));

$srt = "";
foreach($check as $kye => $val)
{
    $title = $val['b_title'][0];
    $var = explode(' ',$title);
    $srt .= trim($var[1]).', ';
}
$srt = substr(trim($srt),0,-1);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use on mentioned URL solution [Click here](https://eval.in/665943)

```
foreach ($arr as $k=>$val) {
    $v = explode (' ', $val['b_title']);
    $out .= $v[1].',';
}
$out = rtrim ($out, ',');
echo '<pre>'; print_r($out); die;
```

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
foreach($test_array as $val)
{
  $new_array[] = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $val['b_title']);
}

$out = implode(',', $new_array);
echo $out;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
10,11,12,13,14,15
```

**[DEMO](https://eval.in/665946)**

Comment: Why should the OP "try this". A good answer will have an explanation of what was done and why. This helps to the OP to understand as well as future visitors to Stack Overflow.